# Upload .EXE to Web for Mac

Tags: mac, windows

I am a windows user, and I am a game developer. I have my .exe file, and I want my friend on Mac to be able to run the program. I know I can use Wine, but my question is, if I upload my .exe file to a website, can a Mac user go on the website and run the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exe file will download like any other file. Then each Mac user needs to have a program to open that file for it to run. That's where they will need virtualization (VMware / VirtualBox / Parallels) or emulation (Wine).

Comment: My question is will it run on mac if I turn in into a web application, not a download

Comment: Yeah, not so much. Exe isn't anything Mac web browsers run, @NathanChan. You would be better screen sharing the pc running exe to the Mac.

Comment: Wine is not an emulator